# Are there rules or exception when using Android styles.xml

Tags: android, xml, styles

I'm trying to style LinearLayout with some padding. The reason is because I have 7-8 similar structured layout and I want them to be synchronized to make adjustment easier.

So here's my layout xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    style="@style/QuestionPane.AnswerPane"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_yes"
        style="@style/ButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="Yes" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_no"
        style="@style/ButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="No" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And styles.xml:

```
<style name="QuestionPane">
    <item name="android:background">@color/question_bg</item>
    <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">50dp</item>
</style>

<style name="QuestionPane.AnswerPane">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">100dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">top|left</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/report_purple</item>
</style>
```

Background color was applied correctly. However, no padding attributes were applied. I have button style with paddings and they work just fine.

```
<style name="ButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_middle</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_bg</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/button_text</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">30dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">30dp</item>
</style>
```

So what's the problem here? Is there some attribute that I cannot do via styles.xml?

Comment: What do you have in `QuestionPane`?

Comment: <item name="android:background">@color/question_bg</item>
<item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
<item name="android:paddingLeft">50dp</item>

Comment: And what it is extending(if extending something)?

Comment: Nothing, I update my question with QuestionPane now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some tests, the problem seems to appear because of the `android:padding` attribute in the parent `QuestionPane` style, setting that values blocks any overriding of the other padding attributes in child styles. I don't know why this happens but I know how to pass by it, avoid the `android:padding` attribute and set the padding for each of the padding attributes:

```
<style name="QuestionPane">
    <item name="android:background">@color/question_bg</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">50dp</item>
</style>
```

This should make the padding appear without other modification to your current code.

Comment: Good call. So what's the purpose of "." in "QuestionPane.AnswerPane"? Is it cascading the style from QuestionPane down to AnswerPane?

Comment: @RobGThai The point represents a subclass of a previous declared style.